# My global axes got rotated

Tags: 3d-view, coordinates

[image]

My global axes are not not level anymore. How can I reset?

So I don't mean an object, but the actual coordinate system.

Comment: Try switching to front view with Numpad 1.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect that to work. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: You can post it as answer and I can check it.

Comment: Coordinate system isn't (and generally can't be) changed, those axes show orientation of viewport camera in the space related to global axes. Which means this small axes sign will always rotate when you rotate the viewport

Answer (score 1):

As [Mr Zak](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96811/my-global-axes-got-rotated#comment171097_96811) and [Brenticus](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96811/my-global-axes-got-rotated#comment171093_96811) pointed out in the comments:

Those arrows are always aligned to the global coordinate system and are rendered from the point of view of the viewport camera:

[image]